# Remove conditional tag from header

Tags: php, conditional-tags

```
            <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'fukasawa_logo' ) ) : ?>

            <a class="blog-logo" href='<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>' title='<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'title' ) ); ?> &mdash; <?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'description' ) ); ?>' rel='home'>
                <img src='<?php echo esc_url( get_theme_mod( 'fukasawa_logo' ) ); ?>' alt='<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'title' ) ); ?>'>
            </a>

        <?php elseif ( get_bloginfo( 'description' ) || get_bloginfo( 'title' ) ) : 

            // h1 on singular, h2 elsewhere
            $title_type = is_singular() ? '2' : '1'; ?>

            <h<?php echo $title_type; ?> class="blog-title">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'title' ) ); ?> &mdash; <?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'description' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'title' ) ); ?></a>
            </h<?php echo $title_type; ?>>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

How can I remove the "check for image logo" part? I only want to use text logo.

Comment: I don't understand. Why not just not set a logo? Or just remove the conditional tag? There must be context here I'm not getting.

Comment: Create a child theme, which will require a `style.css` file with comments defining it as a child theme, and a copy of this file - just remove the lines of code you don't want.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I just wanted to remove unnecessary code, calls, etc. Why have that if I will never use the image logo option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a child theme. You can use a plugin to do that, just search for 'child theme' on the wordpress plugins search.

After that, you need to copy your header.php to the child theme directory.

Then, you need to change the code above to the following:

```
  <?php if ( get_bloginfo( 'description' ) || get_bloginfo( 'title' ) ) : 
        // h1 on singular, h2 elsewhere
        $title_type = is_singular() ? '2' : '1'; ?>
        <h<?php echo $title_type; ?> class="blog-title">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'title' ) ); ?> &mdash; <?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'description' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'title' ) ); ?></a>
        </h<?php echo $title_type; ?>>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

(Just remove the part that checks if an image has been set)

That way, you can update your theme and you won't loose that change.

Comment: I don't want to use child theme but your answer is the solution, works just fine.

Comment: You can do the same thing in the main theme, you will just loose that if you ever update it.
Glad to help =)